# Rewrite URL in .htaccess - PHP

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem with `.htaccess` file and code in that file. I create a simple CMS using PHP. In Fron-End users can view listed products and buy the same. Where is the problem? The problem is when listed product on `localhost/site3/index.php` and the open random product you can view all information about that project, but when the user opens category `products/protection-program/inspection-gloves/index.php` and on that page click on a random product then user get an error **The requested URL was not found on this server**. How to generate `.htaccess` file to support the next URLs.

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-ZA-Z-]+)$ details.php?pro_id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

File `details.php` write-in `.htaccess` the file is stored into `localhost/site3/details.php`. In that file is written code for preview all product information.

I try next:

1. Copy and Paste `details.php` file into `localhost/site3/products/protection-program/inspection-gloves/details.php` and then open some products listed in that category, but won't work.
2. Change `RewriteRule ^([0-9A-ZA-Z-]+)$ details.php?pro_id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]` to `RewriteRule ^([0-9A-ZA-Z-]+)/([0-9A-ZA-Z-]+)/([0-9A-ZA-Z-]+)$ details.php?pro_id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]`. With this change when open random product stored on next URL `localhost/site3/products/protection-program/inspection-gloves/` i get automaticly redirection to `localhost/site3/index.php`. Don't know reason.

***Note: I have some products with less or more categories/sub-categories...***

I want to generate `.htaccess` to support all my URLs. Any advice or help will be helpful. Thanks all!

Comment: "The requested URL was not found on this server" - so what is the URL being requested and what do you expect the URL to be? How are you linking to that URL in the HTML source?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution.

On existing code in `.htaccess` file add next code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/category/subCategory/([0-9A-ZA-Z-]+)$ details.php?pro_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

With that code, I resolve my problem.